# How to detect if IE's Enterprise Mode is disabled by group policy?

Tags: internet-explorer, active-directory, gpo

I am writing an installer for an application that requires that IE run in Enterprise Mode (EM). (Please don't answer with explanations why I shouldn't do that.) EM can be disabled by an Active Directory group policy (if this gets the lingo wrong, please advise). In this case, the user can't enable Enterprise Mode. How can I detect this state in my installer so that i can warn the user to contact their IT administrator to beg them to enable EM? I assume that group policies can be read but a code sample would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible for you to check the values in the registry since you can also enable Enterprise Mode via registry. Though I haven't verified if values in "Sitelist" will be blank if EM is disabled:

Please check:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnterpriseMode.

or

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnterpriseMode.

Some useful links - Turn on Enterprise Mode and use a site list:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640699.aspx

Comment: This registry entry is how Enterprise Mode is enabled but, if a group policy disallows it, it will not have the desired effect. It is this group policy that I want to test. My installer can TRY to enable EM via this registry entry but it won't work (or won't stick) if the group policy is preventing it. I want to know if this is the case so I can warn the user.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I initially thought that you just wanted to know if EM is disabled in the machine so I suggested that your installer program read the values in the registry so you can warn the user. 

You are right, any attempts to change what the group policy pushed will not persist. I'm no expert at policy management but can you ask your admin if policies will be saved in the local policy of the machine where your program can read thru it?

Comment: If it was only a matter of my admin, I would simple tell him not to set a group policy that disables EM. ;-) I am talking about a product that will be installed on other company's machines. This is why my installer must programmatically detect such a group policy.

Comment: You're missing my point, the reason we're going to ask an admin is for us to know if the group policies also shows up or gets reflected as well in the machine's local policy (or any policy for that matter within the machine) where your program can try to read the setting.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Yes, we tried that. Changing the group policy didn't seem to change anything in the client machine's registry. Some time after setting the group policy, the registry setting that enables EM is cleared. Presumably, this is the result of group policy being applied to the local machine based on some sort of refresh interval. The group policy seems not to actually prevent EM from being enabled but it will magically (to the user) clear it some time later.

Answer (score 0):

One answer we've found is that the gpresult program can be run on the client machine to produce a report the group policies. Our installer could presumably run this program and parse its output to find the setting. Of course, if gpresult can read the group policy, there are likely Windows APIs called by gpresult that my installer can call directly. If anyone knows what these calls are, please reply.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little searching to find out how we might do what gpresult does programmatically. This is a bit stream-of-consciousness as I reported what I found in the order I found it:

The gpresult utility is used to report on RSoP (Resultant Set of Policy). As the name implies, this gives the result of all the policy settings. A good summary can be found in Performing Resultant Set of Policy Queries with the GPRESULT Tool. It says:

```
If you are a consultant who works on other people’s networks though, you don’t usually have the luxury of being intimately familiar with the network’s configuration. If you get called in to diagnose a problem on a client’s network, you may be able to determine that the problem is group policy related in a matter of minutes. However, it can take days to figure out exactly which group policy element is causing the problem because the group policy can be so complex.
```

So the bottom line is that we are probably much better off using the output from gpresult to detect the Enterprise Mode group policy than writing a bunch of code to do it. On the other hand, there appears to be APIs that directly query the RSoP: How to retrieve currently applied GPOs on your local machine using WMI via Windows Scripting Host (WSH). While this article has code written to be run in WSH, I believe the analogous thing can be done in C++ code. This sample dumps the dictionary structure returned by the API to the console. Our code would presumably just check a single value in the dictionary. Or perhaps it has to find a certain setting in the dictionary. If found, its value is examined. If not found, it can be assumed there is no group policy set.

There is a way to do RSoP queries in C++. The starting point appears to be IGPM::GetRSOP.